# How to insert SharePoint metadata(Picture) into your Word document?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Document Library with column type Hyperlink or Picture (Signature).

How  to insert (Signature) into your Word document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
```

you can call the InsertAPicture method by passing in the path of the word document, and the path of the file that contains the picture.

```
string document = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Word9.docx";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyPic.jpg";
InsertAPicture(document, fileName);


public static void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName)
{
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = 
    WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

    ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        imagePart.FeedData(stream);
    }

    AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
}
}

   private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
  {
   // Define the reference of the image.
var element =
     new Drawing(
         new DW.Inline(
             new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
             new DW.EffectExtent() { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, 
                 RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L },
             new DW.DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, 
                 Name = "Picture 1" },
             new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                 new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
             new A.Graphic(
                 new A.GraphicData(
                     new PIC.Picture(
                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                             new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties() 
                                { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, 
                                    Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg" },
                             new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                         new PIC.BlipFill(
                             new A.Blip(
                                 new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                     new A.BlipExtension() 
                                        { Uri = 
                                            "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" })
                             ) 
                             { Embed = relationshipId, 
                                 CompressionState = 
                                 A.BlipCompressionValues.Print },
                             new A.Stretch(
                                 new A.FillRectangle())),
                         new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                             new A.Transform2D(
                                 new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                 new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                             new A.PresetGeometry(
                                 new A.AdjustValueList()
                             ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                 ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
         ) { DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U, 
             DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U, 
             DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U, 
             DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U, EditId = "50D07946" });

   // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
   wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Images from a SharePoint list or library can be inserted into a library using the 'Document Property' under 'Quick Parts'. Images and URLs are not normally supported for this but a quick conversion of the URL to a text field gets around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Word Automation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558830.aspx). They allow you to merge different documents into one.
Also you can always build your own Word document: [Generating Documents from SharePoint with Open XML Content Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532473.aspx)

Comment: thanks , but Content Control Types in Open Xml : Picture

·   Allows a single value (image)

·   Not a container

·   Not Bind able   ... [plz check this link](http://blogs.staffdotnet.com/johanngranados/blog/default.aspx?id=31&t=Content-Control-Types-in-Open-Xml-Part)